# Time series (stochastic process) estimating parameters using characteristic function

Tags: time-series, estimation, stochastic-processes, characteristic-function

I have a time series of assets ${A_1, A_2, ..., A_n}$, which is described by a sophisticated distribution having the following characteristic function:  $\phi(u; t;\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a vector of unknown parameters. 
I need to esimate vector of unknown parameters $\theta$ of characteristic function.

I tried to find a PDF using the inverse Fourier transform to use the maximum likelihood method, but the characteristic function is too complicated for that.
I also thought about building the empirical characteristic function using the time series of assets and to estimate parameters using the least square method, but I do not know how to build the empirical characteristic function, because time series is not just a sample of random variables, it is a random process that depends on time.

Comment: It seems that what you are asking for is actually a PhD thesis of someone! Check out [this](http://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/s4/f2/dsk2/ftp02/NQ31169.pdf).